# Assigning every other word in the list to be printed in python

Tags: python, for-loop, split

I am reading a file, where only 1st and 3rd column are of interest to me. After collecting the timestamps from 1st column and product names from the 3rd and storing the data in the list, I intend to print a message: "Timestamp X for product Y". Below is what I have now:

```
def reading_file():
    file_reading = open("marjoja.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") 
    # removing the header
    file_reading.readline()
    products = []
    while (True):
        row = file_reading.readline() 
        if len(row) == 0: 
            break
        else:
            # collecting data from 1 and 3 columns
            lines = row.split(';')[0::2]
            #products.append(row.split(';')[0::2])
            products.extend(lines)
    file_reading.close()
    return products

def main():
    products = reading_file()
    product_lst = str(products).split("\n")
    for lines in product_lst:
        if lines == "0":
            break
        else:
            print("Time", lines.split()[1], "on product", lines.split()[0],".")
  

main()
```

The output from print(products) would be along the line of: ['jordans', '00:00\n', 'polish', '02:13\n']. What I wanted to produce in main was - "Time 00:00 for jordans". What I am generating instead is: "Time '00:00\n' for ['jordans', . How would I assign the words from the list to the proper location?

Comment: You're processing every other line of the file. Move the `removing the header` part before the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strip()` to remove newlines when reading.

Return a list of lists, rather than extending `products` as a flat list. Then you don't need to convert `products` to a string and split it again.

```
def reading_file():
    products = []

    with open("marjoja.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file_reading:
        # removing the header
        file_reading.readline()

        for row in file_reading:
            row = row.strip()
            # collecting data from 1 and 3 columns
            lines = row.split(';')[0::2]
            products.append(lines)

    return products

def main():
    products = reading_file()
    for (product, time) in product_lst:
        print(f"Time {time} for product {product}.")
  
main()
```